# How to handle optional property that has a value in defaultProps?

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

I got the following class component:

```js
type Props = {
    required: string;
    optional?: string;
};

class TestComp extends Component<Props> {
  static defaultProps = {
    optional: "dff"
  }
    render() {
    // ERROR: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
    this.props.optional.length
    return "abcd";
  }
}
```

Why is `this.props.optional.length` causing an error? I'm using TS 4.3 and React v17, I thought that this issue was fixed in 3.0 in this PR: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23812 (see the second block of code) Or am I misunderstanding this fix, its just for fixing this issue in JSX code?

If possible I would not make the `optional` prop required, I think this would confuse users who are instantiating the prop object (why is a prop required when its optional?)

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDeBhCcCAOyWJgF84AzKQuAIilQwYG4AoDmATzCTgAFOmADOcALy4OcGhAgB+AFxxRMKMGIBzTrIBGKKCrUbtnCpw5IAHpFhwAJkmooArgBt4adylHiAYvIAQoZwNjBkDuIERKTkADzCEGIAfNKyYK567sBoqjAoMLmOzm6eSWKS6bJyECoA5NTyAIT1MnAWXBlZOXnMxE5QABQAlNWyaCRqtVUwABbAogB0YCLLTRBL7mRa87o1k8TTBlCzC8urycsnWzt77bLMMK5QxHDxDsAAbik4AAYAEhwGyoQJOFD+FHiAHpPj99hQOIjodC4PMkKIBKI5hAPA44HokHMUF8BJMoMxvLw0fJuHwBIEICEoBVxFJkOgYEsYpA4jBWfFePwINQ4IzmSlOIdppcxCpxYZWVUcO0Tg05kgeG1OtL4GAwColVIcGrGABGABMAGYGBQgA)

Answer (score 0):

Please see this [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24422#issuecomment-395168742)

In order to make it work, you should make your `optional` property required.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

type Props = {
    required: string;
    optional: string;
};

class TestComp extends Component<Props> {
    static defaultProps = {
        optional: "dff"
    }
    render() {
        // ERROR: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
        this.props.optional.length
        return "abcd";
    }
}
const x = <TestComp required="sdf" /> // no error
```

See, there is no error. TS is able to figure out that `static defaultProps` will assure that `optional` prop will always be a non empty string

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.0-beta#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecDCE4EAdkifAL5wBmURcA5FKhowFDswCeYScABXpgAznAC8udnBlwWARwCuwFgBMAXHBEwowEgHMA3NNkQwMYKRQAbTdt0HjlY%20zTWUIsQBUk2wuDgkAA8YclUxf0gyCgAeITMRAD4pWS0YFAs0OFUkGhRFaxh40QkU1NNzSxIbTQAiVRoaWpMZSha5MKQoAAoASjLyuAB6IbgAUQQEAHkETSmAIwArJAw4YDFIT2B5624mRRIcmj0kVUYAOnbUmAALdfOwYRFzswsra3Prcn1bq9kWGCKKAkOC1FDzNCqWrGVJtNpoUjaOBBUoxHx%20IhgDpKFSncS1EQNWrDRKcIA)

Comment: I mentioned at the bottom of my comment, that if possible I would like *not* to make my optional prop required. This introduces a weird behavior if I want to instantiate/use the props separately (why is an optional prop required? Why does `React.ComponentProps` return that a prop is required when its optional in the docs?)

Comment: oh, overlooked it. I'm not sure it is possible

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this is not supported as of TypeScript 4.3.5.

There are some workarounds, but for me they either come with downsides or are way too complex: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30251

We have decided to leave optional props optional even if they have a `defaultProps` value, and in the code we use the `?` operator and do null/undefined checks -- this also takes care of the case that the user sets the value to `undefined` or `null`